# Deploying ReactJS with Axios on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, apache, axios, cors, web-deployment

We have 2 different server:

```
Front end: http://front-end.com
Back end: http://back-end.com
```

The react part is just the `http://front-end.com` that I am trying to deploy

Those 2 are connected using Axios, it works fine on my local using `npm start`
by putting `proxy: http://back-end.com` on the `package.json`

#### Issue

When I deploy it the REST API connection using axios couldn't work at all

**1st attempt:** serving the apache to run to the `build` folder
**Error:** homepage loaded, but 404 on all REST call, upon inspecting it tries to access `http://front-end.com/rest_method_name` instead of `http://back-end.com/rest_method_name` that it supposed to access

**2nd attempt:** running on the `serve -s build` as suggested
**Error**: homepage loaded, but all REST call returns this text `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` on the body

**3rd attempt:** removing proxy on `package.json`, then put the full url on all axios call
**Error**: homepage loaded, all REST call got CORS error and doesn't run

Can anyone let me know how to deploy react and Axios correctly if the backend sits on a different domain name?

**EDIT**
As requested by @technogeek1995, here is the Axios request header

```
  axios.get('/login', {
    'headers': {
      'Authorization': `Basic ${token}`
    }
  })
```

I don't have any other settings, other than that and the `proxy: http://back-end.com` and the above Axios code

**EDIT 2**
I've added the CORS header as suggested, still no luck. The same error CORS issue. I have also made sure I have enabled the `a2enmod header`

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, author    ization, accept, client-security-token"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Comment: You can temporarily disable CORS for development by using Access CORS plugin (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en)

Furthermore, I think you need to read up on CORS and how to enable it from your BE server. If you are using NodeJS for BE, this should be of help https://medium.com/@alexishevia/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b

Comment: As stated above, if you're having CORS issues, the issue is on `OPTIONS` request sent by Axios to the server before sending `POST`/`GET`/etc. The issue **must** be resolved on the server by whitelisting `http://front-end.com` with your CORS configuration. If you need help doing that, I would edit your question to add your REST server configuration, details, description to resolve the question.

Comment: I've editted the question above, also trying to enable the Apache header and adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, but no luck

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I asked around and finally found the issue. I was completely looking to a wrong direction, I kept looking on the `http://front-end.com` server.

CORS issue is generated from the backend server `http://back-end.com` in my example case.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

That need to be added on the backend server serving the REST API.